# Do the basic Xbox One models (non-X) support enhancements in the backwards compatible Xbox 360 games?

Tags: xbox-one

[Xbox One currently has 25 "X enhanced games" Xbox 360 games](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/) which are rendered at 4K on Xbox One X, a nine-time increase over 360's 720p resolution. Compatible original Xbox games have their resolution multiplied to the nearest native value on all Xbox One models, but are improvements to the 360 titles X-exclusive? According to [this Forbes contributor article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kevinmurnane/2018/04/14/red-dead-redemption-raises-the-bar-for-xbox-one-x-enhanced-xbox-360-games/) Red Dead Redemption runs at 1080p on Xbox One S which may suggest that at least the S model benefits from the X-enhancements.

Also, do all the other 360 run at the original resolution (720p) on every variation of the console?

Comment: Digital Foundry has almost certainly answered this question, but considering how much research they've done about backwards compatibility it isn't easy to find the applicable videos/articles. https://www.eurogamer.net/digitalfoundry https://www.youtube.com/user/DigitalFoundry/videos

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers to your questions, so i'll try to be brief. The short answer is *no*, not officially. But, due to the improved hardware on your *Xbox One*, titles from the *Xbox 360* stick to their frame rate caps a lot better than they did on the 360. For example, GTA V might've given you 22-30 frames on the *360*, whereas the *Xbox One* will more than likely give you the full 30 at all times. Also, a lot of TV's upscale, so that could help with the visuals. Other than that, The *Xbox One X* is the only (Microsoft) console that actually *Performance Mode* for certain titles.

Comment: [360 games also have V-sync universally enabled on Xbox One](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2015-vs-backwards-compatibility-on-xbox-one) when screentearing was common on the original platform in games.

Comment: You didn't mention the resolution (Red Dead Redemption: 720p < 1080p)

Comment: I apologize @user598527 . What information did you need to know about the resolution? The only upscaling i am aware of on console side is on the Xbox One X. You can read about exactly how they upscale the content. My goal was to provide an answer to the title question. The normal Xbox One only really enhances frame rates.

Comment: It however seems that at least the S model can run games at a higher resolution. I've contacted the Digital Foundry team on Twitter and they hopefully can resolve this topic.

Comment: @user598527 This article might give you some insight: https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2016-vs-xbox-one-backward-compatibility. As far as the Xbox One S, It will do the same as the Xbox One. The only difference is that the Xbox One S has slightly better performance and will probably emulate the 360 games better.